# »Wie ist« oder »Wie seid Ihr Name«?

Tags: personal-pronoun, grammar-identification, grammatical-person

Wieso sagt man »Wie ist Ihr Name?« anstatt »Wie seid Ihr Name?« Das Personalpronomen *Sie* (Höflichkeitsanrede) wird ja mit *sind* dekliniert. Aber hier wird *ist* benutzt. Auf welchen grammatischen Regel bezieht sich nun das bitte?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plural:

> Wie **sind** Ihre Name**n**?
>   Wie **sind** deine Name**n**?
>   Wie **sind** eure Name**n**?

Singular:

> Wie **ist** Ihr Name?
>   Wie **ist** dein Name?
>   Wie **ist** euer Name?

Das Verb bezieht sich auf das Substantiv im Objekt (Name/Namen) und muss mit diesem im Numerus übereinstimmen.

Das Personalpronomen ist ein Attribut des Substantivs und bildet mit diesem gemeinsam das Nominativobjekt (Ihr/dein/euer Name, Ihre/deine/eure Namen). Auch das Attribut (also das Pronomen) muss mit dem Objekt im Numerus übereinstimmen.

Aber ob im Fall der Du-Anrede »dein/deine«« oder »euer/eure« zu verwenden ist, hängt von der Anzahl der angesprochenen Personen ab, und diese Anzahl muss dem Kontext entnommen werden:

> Hallo, schöne Frau! Wie ist dein Name?
>
> Ihr seid ja die neue Band, die morgen auftreten wird. Wie ist euer Name? Bisher kennt euch noch niemand. Wie sind eure Namen?

Im Fall der Sie-Anrede sind die Pronomen zufällig gleich:

> Guten Tag, gnädige Frau! Wie ist Ihr<sub>(Singular)</sub> Name?
>
> Sie sind ja das neue Orchester, das morgen auftreten wird. Wie ist Ihr<sub>(Plural)</sub> Name? Bisher kennt Sie noch niemand. Wie sind Ihre Namen?

Comment: Bedanke mich herzlich für die ausführliche Erklaerung Herr Schölnast . Nur noch ne kurze Frage . Ich habe den Satz "Sie seid ja das neue Orchester, das morgen auftreten wird" nicht richtig gut verstanden. Warum wird also hier das Hilfsverb "sein" als "seid" konjugiert ?

Comment: @Chieron: Ich hab's ausgebessert. Sorry, ich hatte gestern keine Zeit mehr, meine Antwort korrekturzulesen. Aber da deine Reputation größer als 1000 ist, kannst du solche offensichtlichen Fehler auch selbst ausbessern sobald du sie bemerkst. (Du darfst nicht nur, sondern du sollst sogar, außer du würdest dadurch inhaltlich etwas verändern, was nicht der Intention des Verfassers entspricht.)

Comment: @GökselOgalan: Weil ich gestern nicht mehr die Zeit hatte, meinen Beitrag korrekturzulesen, und weil niemand von denen, die den Fehler bemerkt haben, sich die Mühe gemacht haben, ihn richtigzustellen. Jetzt steht es richtig dort.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast da der Beitrag erst 30 Minuten alt war, hab ich lieber drauf hingewiesen. Zumindest bei der Aussprache böte sich übrigens noch an, den dritten Fall (3.Person Singular, fem.) noch aufzuzeigen. *(Siehst du die Frau dahinten? Wie ist ihr Name?)* - wobei hier noch mehr auffällt, dass man eher fragt, wie ein Name *lautet* oder wie jemand *heißt*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Danke für die Korrektur.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is that "Name" is the subject of this sentence, not "Sie". You can also notice this, because of the non-nominative case of "Sie" (Ihr).

"Seid" is the presence form of "sein" in 2nd person plural, not the form of "sein" in Höflichkeitsform (3rd person plural).

Comment: Thx for the explanation. It was really hard for me to explain the reason to my students of this gramatical situation. Compared with english it seems to be different.

Comment: That's not different with English. In English you also say "is" ("what is your name? ") and not "what are your name?" (because "you" is used with "are").